# Getting exception WARN org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, rscript

I am adding print statement in existing working R script for some debug purpose.

```
print("Hello")
```

and I am getting the Broken pipe exception while executing this code using Hadoop streaming. if i remove this print again it works , sounds strange to me !!
while editing Rscript i am using vi via window gitbash. 
Could you please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If your Hadoop cluster is made of Linux nodes and you submit a script which was edited in windows or window gitbash, it will fail to run and throw misleading exception. Just edit the file in linux using vi or emacs. Or convert the file from dos format to linux format using do2unix command. (this will remove trailing \r\n and replaces with \n).

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. 

I tried Rscript to open in Vi editor,but that problem was not resolved. 

I opened script file in WinSCP only, which I was using for transferring files from one machine to another. It resolved my issue.